# Data-specific user permissions model / schema design

Tags: permissions, domain-driven-design, database-schema, acl, microservices

My app manages user data that is shared between users, with different permissions such as read-only, edit, superuser, rename, delete etc.

I'm weighing up two approaches to modelling the user permissions, the first is the simpler approach, the second involves more work but is more extensible, refactorable, *I think*.

(1) quick solution, hard-coding against `user permission` properties:

```
-- basic data
CREATE TABLE symbol (
    id INT,
    name VARCHAR(255)
);

CREATE TABLE user (
    id CHAR(10) 
);

CREATE TABLE user_permission (
    symbol_id INT,
    user_id CHAR(10),
    readable BIT,
    writable BIT,
    owner BIT,
    rename BIT,
    deletion BIT
);
```

(2) complete solution, hard-coding against `entitlements`:

[image]

The areas I'm considering are:

1. extensibility - need or not to change model & schema
2. microservices - possibilities to spin off into a separate DB?
3. performance - filter algos, number of joins in queries
4. no-sql caching - no idea but denormalising user permissions sounds crazy
5. admin for users - need good UX
6. admin for DBAs/Support - don't want complaints and endless support requests
7. web services API simplicity / complexity using Spring Data REST - HAL

I'd like to go with the more complex solution since it is unlikely to require re-working in the future, but I'm a bit concerned about both performance and the admin tasks involved in the UI to allow users to manage it.

A utopian solution would be a third-party Java-based webapp providing a user interface to allow admin.

EDIT: interesting to see other people tackling the same problem: [Authorisation in microservices - how to approach domain object or entity level access control using ACL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41161769/authorisation-in-microservices-how-to-approach-domain-object-or-entity-level-a)

Comment: Use KISS and YAGNI. Also denormalising is trivial in CQRS.

Comment: I'm all for KISS but YAGNI is often too subjective, and abused in situations where a small effort now would save a lot of effort later. I would love to know how denormalising can be trivial in CQRS when you have access lists involved. If I denormalise completely, a 50 user access list would cause the data volume to explode.

Comment: Can you use Postgres, which supports column security and row security?

Answer (score 0):

Since it is hard to get security related software right, I would recommend not implementing your own solution but using an existing open source solution. At the time of writing the [Hydra](https://github.com/ory/hydra) project seems most promising. Specifically look at the [access control features](https://ory.gitbooks.io/hydra/content/access-control.html) for your use case.

Comment: v. interesting but it has no front-end which pretty much rules it out if I find anything that does already.